# Resolving opening and closing of JavaScript modal

Tags: javascript, css

The following code is an attempt to create a modal system that allows for multiple images to pop up on click **without reloading the page**.  To do that I leveraged some JavaScript that I found on w3schools.com.  I now have it working, but **not** exactly how I want it.

Problem #1:  It takes a double click on the image to open the modal.

Problem #2:  The only way to close the modal is to click the 'X'.  I would like to be able to click anywhere outside the modal to close it.

Problem #3:  I would really like to fade the background when the modal is open.

The first two problems are really annoying.  The third one would be nice.

Thanks for any help you can give.

DonB

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.86, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=0.86">
    <style>
        .popImage {
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .popImage:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .popModal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 5px; /* Location of the box */
            padding-bottom: 5px; /* Location of the box */
            padding-right: 5px; /* Location of the box */
            padding-left: 5px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 200px;
            top: 100px;
            width: 300px; /* Full width */
            overflow: hidden; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(198, 197, 197); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(198, 197, 197, 0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* popModal Content (image) */
        .popModal-content {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            height: 80%; /* Full height */
            max-width: 350px;
        }
        .popcentered {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            /* bring your own prefixes */
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        /* Caption of popModal Image */
        #caption {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 350px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #ccc;
            padding: 10px 0;
            height: 150px;
        }

        /* Add Animation */
        .popModal-content, #caption {
            -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
            animation-name: zoom;
            animation-duration: 0.6s;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
            from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
            to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
        }

        @keyframes zoom {
            from {transform:scale(0)}
            to {transform:scale(1)}
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 2px;
            right: 10px;
            color: #f1f1f1;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #aaa;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
            .popModal-content {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="popModal popcentered"  id="imgPopModal"  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-md" role="document" style="color:black;justify-content: center;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body"  id="screenSet18b" style="background-color: white; color: black:justify-content: center;padding-top:5px">
                    <span class="close" style="color: black;" data-dismiss="imgPopModal" >&times;</span>
                    <img class="popModal-content" id="img01" style="width: 250px">
                    <div id="caption"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<h2>Image Modal Test</h2>
<div style="align-content: center">
<img id="128650" class="popImage" src="images/available/128650_90.jpg" alt='<a href="https://ziggysdev.com/index.php">6 in. x 6 in. Black Trifit Steel Corner Pergola Bracket</a>' style="width:100px;max-width:300px" onClick="ShowModalImage(128650)">
<img id="128600" src="images/available/128600.JPG" alt="4 in. x 4 in. Black Unifit Steel Post Base and Wall Mount Pergola Bracket" style="width:100px;max-width:300px" onClick="ShowModalImage(128600)">
<img id="111105" src="images/available/111105_81.jpg" alt="10.1 oz. DYNAFLEX White Silicone Sealant" style="width:100px;max-width:300px" onClick="ShowModalImage(111105)">
<img id="111022" src="images/available/111022_81.jpg" alt="Frost King Poly Foam Caulk Saver 3/8inx20" style="width:100px;max-width:300px" onClick="ShowModalImage(111022)">
</div>

<script>
    function ShowModalImage(imageID) {

        // Get the popModal
        var modal = document.getElementById("imgPopModal");

        // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        img.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can see the code in operation at: https://ziggys.com/imagePopTest.php

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I wasnt able to recreate your exact images. But this is an example of 1 image and the Modal. This should help.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image that opens the modal
var img = document.getElementById("image");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the image, open the modal
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->

<img src = "https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" id = "image"></img>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>This is a modal. </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hunter.  That works fine for a single image but it doesn't do it when there are multiple images triggered by  onClick="JavaScript function()" in the <img statement.